# Can I make QPainter fonts operate in the same units as everything else?

Tags: qt, fonts

I started with this

```
void draw_text (QPainter & p, const QString & text, QRectF target)
{
    float scale = calculate_font_scale (p, text, target); // about 0.0005

    QFont f = p .font ();
    float old_size = f .pointSizeF ();
    f .setPointSizeF (old_size * scale);
    p .setFont (f);

    // this prints the new font size correctly
    qWarning ("old: %f, new: %f", old_size, p .font () .pointSizeF ());

    // but that doesn't seem to affect this at all
    p .drawText (position, text);
}
```

The QPainter's font has size has been correctly updated, as the qWarning line indicates, but the text draws much, much to big. I think this is because the QPainter coordinate system has been zoomed-in quite a lot and [it seems setPointSizeF only works with sizes of at least 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3949877/coordinate-scaling-causes-too-large-font-sizes-in-qpainterdrawtext). By eye it seems that the font is one "unit" high so I'll buy that explanation, although it's stupid.

I experimented with using `setPixelSize` instead, and although `p.fontMetrics().boundingRect(text)` yields a sane-looking answer, it is given in *pixel units*. **One requirement for the above-function is that the bounding rect of the text is horizontally and vertically centred with respect to the `target` argument**, which is in coordinates of  a vastly different scale, so the arithmetic is no longer valid and the text is drawn miles off-screen.

I want to be able to transform the coordinate system arbitrarily and if, at the point, one "unit" is a thousand pixels high and I'm drawing text in a 0.03x0.03 unit box then I want the font to be 30 pixels high, obviously, but I need all my geometry to be calculated in general units all the time, and I need `fontMetrics::boundingRect` to be in these same general units.

Is there any way out of this or do I have to dick around with pixel calculations to appease the font API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply have to undo whatever "crazy" scaling there was on the painter.

```cpp
// Save the state
p.save();
// Translate the center of `target` to 0,0.
p.translate(-target.center());
// Scale so that the target has a "reasonable" size
qreal dim = 256.0;
qreal sf = dim/qMin(target.height(), target.width());
p.scale(sf, sf);
// Draw your text
p.setPointSize(48);
p.drawText(QRectF(dim, dim), Qt::AlignCenter | Qt::WordWrap, text);
// Restore the state
p.restore();
```

Comment: This is exactly the kind of solution I was trying to avoid. Seems hacky. Why should the target have "reasonable" size? It's all vectors and Béziers underneath, right?

Comment: @spraff You play the hands you're dealt. This may be a limitation of either native or 3rdparty font system. All this bunch of code does is change the transformation matrix, it's rather trivial under the hood. I don't think it's jacky much, except that you have to be more clever about the rectangle dimensions (I've "squared it up")