# Why is QRect::moveCenter not working as expected?

Tags: c++, qt

This is the solution I'm working on for [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21912824/can-i-make-qpainter-fonts-operate-in-the-same-units-as-everything-else). The text needs to be horizontally and vertically centered in the given `rect`.

```
void
draw_text_label (QPainter & p, const QString & text, QRectF rect)
{
    // Work in unscaled coordinates (see linked question if you're curious)

    p .save ();
    assert (false == p .transform () .isRotating ());
    rect = p .transform () .mapRect (rect);
    p .resetTransform ();

    // Scale to fit

    set_font_size (p, font_size_to_fit (p, text, rect));

    QRectF text_rect = p .fontMetrics () .tightBoundingRect (text);

    ////////////////////////////
    // this line ALMOST works //
    ////////////////////////////

    text_rect .moveCenter (rect .center ());

    // Draw

    p .translate (text_rect .left (), text_rect .bottom ());

    p .setPen (Qt :: red);
    p .drawText (0, 0, text);
    p .drawRect (0, 0, text_rect .width (), -text_rect .height ());

    p .restore ();
}
```

Which is called by

```
void
draw_thingy (QRectF rect)
{
    p .setPen (Qt :: white);
    p .drawRect (rect);

    float m = MARGIN * 0.5;
    draw_text_label (thingy_text, rect .adjusted (m,m,-2*m,-2*m));
}
```

In summary, the given `rect` is indicated in white, the `text_rect` is indicated in red.

[image]

As you can see in this test image ([link in case the inline image dies](http://postimg.org/image/ha8rq5q3j/)), the red rectangle isn't quite centered. This is more than a rounding error.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

Use the alignment value `Qt::AlignCenter` in `DrawText` to center the text in the rect. No rect calculations required.

Comment: That seems to be producing the exact same result.

Comment: Might have something to do with the transform you're applying to the painter. Try commenting out all transform code